# Upgraded to OS Lion and now I get Error 51 and my VPN Client wont start up

Tags: vpn, osx-lion, operating-systems

I need help. I upgraded to OS Lion and now my VPN client wont start up and I get Error 51. I have tried all the fixes I found on the web but nothing worked. Is there a new fix for OS Lion? Thanks!